# Add a dynamic Raster Layer with arcgis for javascript

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

As u know, it's easy to Add a dynamic shp layer with FeatureLayer Class in arcgis for javascript, i thought it's same in Raster Layer, but no, so how can i Add a dynamic Raster Layer with arcgis for javascript?

Comment: What version of the API are you using? Do you have access to ArcGIS Online and/or ArcGIS Server?

Comment: soory, i should describe my question elaborately:arcgis server, api version is 3.26, and thank you, i find the way to solve that,i put them in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer @Below the Radar, my situation is that I have a number of layers to show , so i can't publish them as service, I found that it support dynamic layer after ArcGIS Server v10.1, but yesterday I don't found how to add a Raster Layer dynamicly (not as a MapService), now i have solved this problem, here's that code:

```
var dynamicLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/labWorldFolder/labWorldService/MapServer");
var map = new Map("mapDiv");
map.addLayer(dynamicLayer); 

$("#btnAddRasterLayer").click(function() {
    var dynamicLayerInfos = [];
    var dynamicLayerInfo = new DynamicLayerInfo();  // set dynamicLayerInfo
    dynamicLayerInfo.id = 1;

    var dataSource = new RasterDataSource();        // define a rasterDataSource
    dataSource.workspaceId = "labWorldRasterWS";
    dataSource.dataSourceName = "./test_d.img";

    var layerSource = new LayerDataSource();      
    layerSource.dataSource = dataSource;

    dynamicLayerInfo.source = layerSource;  
    dynamicLayerInfos.push(dynamicLayerInfo);

    dynamicLayer.setDynamicLayerInfos(dynamicLayerInfos, false);
});
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged your question with arcgis-server, I assume you have access to ArcGIS Server or ArcGIS Online.

With ArcGIS javascript API v4.9, you can add a raster layer published in MapService using a [`MapImageLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-MapImageLayer.html) with [`RasterDataSource`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-support-Sublayer.html#RasterDataSource) [`subLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-support-Sublayer.html).

1. Add your raster layer(s) into a workspace with ArcMap or ArcPro
2. Publish your workspace to ArcGIS Server or ArcGIS Online as a MapService
3. With the javascript API v4.9, instantiate a [`MapImageLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-MapImageLayer.html) using the url or your MapService

   ```
   var layer = new MapImageLayer({
       url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services  /USA/MapServer",  //map service url
       sublayers: [{
           title: "Slope",
           source: {
               type: "data-layer",
               dataSource: {
                   type: "raster",
                   workspaceId: "MyDatabaseWorkspaceIDSSR2", //registered workspace id,
                   dataSourceName: "slope" //raster name
               }
           }
       }]
   });
   ```

See this example: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-dynamicdatalayer-raster/index.html